# How to get group representation of the cyclic group $C_3 = \{1,u,u^2\}$ where $u = e^{2\pi i / 3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I grasped the concept of group representation, but I am not sure how to get group representation of the cyclic group $C_3 = \{1,u,u^2\}$ where $u = e^{2\pi i / 3}$. Let's say we want to get a representation $\rho$ on $\textbf{C}^2$. How does one do this?

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase your question, you are looking for a homomorphism $\rho:C_3\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

There is always the trivial representation, which sends everything to the identity matrix.

Another way, which is less trivial, is to find a representation $\sigma$ of $C_3$ on $\mathbb{C}$ (hint: $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^\times$, the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers), then construct a representation $\rho$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by making elements of $C_3$ act "coordinate-wise" on elements of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Your should know that all *irreducible* representations of  the abelian group $C_{3}$ are one-dimensional.

There are three of them, given by
$$
C_{3} \to \operatorname{GL}_{1}(\Bbb{C}) \cong \Bbb{C}^{\times}, \qquad u \mapsto u^{k}, 
$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2$.

So to get a two-dimensional representation, just combine any two of these. Among the various choices, the one
$$
C_{3} \to \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\Bbb{C}), \qquad u \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}u&0\\0&u^{2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
is probably particularly interesting, as it can be realized over the reals:
$$
C_{3} \to \operatorname{GL}_{2}(\Bbb{R}), \qquad u \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
(But see Jyrki Lahtonen's comment below for the much more natural representation:-) in terms of rotations.)

Comment: +1: Agree that the latter representation is interesting because it can be realized over the reals. I would also consider using the (isomorphic as a representation) mapping
$$u\mapsto\pmatrix{\cos\frac{2\pi}3&-\sin\frac{2\pi}3\cr
\sin\frac{2\pi}3&\cos\frac{2\pi}3\cr}.$$ After all, this representation often occurs, when a planar geometric object has threefold rotational symmetry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you're absolutely right, I went absent-mindedly for the Jordan form, but of course it's rotations, and much more natural that way.